# Compare two String with android

Tags: android

This is my method for reading a txt file in the raw folder:

```
public static String readTextFile(Activity activity,int rawId){
    InputStream inputStream = activity.getResources().openRawResource(rawId);
    System.out.println(inputStream);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int i;
    try {
        i = inputStream.read();
        while (i != -1)
        {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
            i = inputStream.read();
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
}
```

My code for equal :

```
String read_text= partsViewModel.getImageAddress().trim();// read_text is dc18b7f823e94dcb85a5f38845300324
if (read_text.equals("dc18b7f823e94dcb85a5f38845300324")) {
    // equal
} else {
    // not equal
}
```

Why is read_text not equal with dc18b7f823e94dcb85a5f38845300324 ?

Comment: So you already printed out `read_text ` to see its value?

Comment: Please be more specific in your question description with regards to what exactly you are trying to achieve. It's like a puzzle to read the brief title, and just copy-pasted code.

Comment: `read_text is dc18b7f823e94dcb85a5f38845300324` apparently not. what makes you say so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your file in raw folder is a different encoding, you may not get a true from equals().

you need to watch out byteArrayOutputStream.toString(), try

> byteArrayOutputStream.toString("ISO-8859-1")

or

> byteArrayOutputStream.toString("utf-8")

Also, your code is

```
 partsViewModel.getImageAddress().trim()
```

you should also make sure if it is actually come from your readTextFile code.